# How to send a data from a variable using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

how can I send a generated variable which have a data of text and send its content to ajax ?

**i.e**

```
var name = $('#name').val();
```

and then after send this variable context to an ajax function the ajax functions is

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "insert.php",
            method: "post",
            data:{name:name},
            dataType:"text",
            success:function(data){
                alert('Success it works!')
            }
         });

  });
```

php is

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mydb");

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['name']);

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO user_info(`name`) VALUE('$name')";
mysqli_query($con,$sql2);

?>
```

do not question me if i do not used to serialized my form data we have different application of the logic in our systems which in my case i dont have form, i activate ajax callback function using button, so this is my case, really need help to send these variable data to a php.

P.S. please not JSON thanks! :)

Comment: You're doing it right, what is your problem?

Comment: Specifically how is this failing?  The AJAX code looks like it's including the value.  When you check your browser's debugging tools, is that value being sent to the server?  Where is it lost?

Comment: Maybe your data type is wrong, try `json`.

Comment: Your not returning anything? `echo "something";`

Comment: Ajax code seems fine : maybe you should check for `var name = $('#name').val();` not being empty before sending it, then check again on the php side ->  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on top of your page then `print_r($_POST);` EDIT: what console says ?

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string deprecated if you're using new php version !! may be that's what cause the error

Comment: oh I forgot to ask do i need a `form.on(submit)` ??